# Class cast exception when using Spring ldap

Tags: java, spring, spring-ldap

When using spring ldap to perform searches, I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx cannot be cast to org.springframework.ldap.core.DirContextAdapter
```

I am using a java SE utility, which performs a kerberos login using JAAS, and runs code to query an ldap server using spring-ldap as a privileged action.

I do not use any particular spring configuration in my application.
Can someone indicate what I'm doing wrong?
Many thanks. I am suing spring-ldap 1.3.1.RELEASE

Comment: You are trying to turn a `LdapCtx` into a `DirContextAdapter` somewhere. Without a stacktrace or code it is hard to tell you any more than that.

Comment: Thanks, I will add stacktrace.